# La consulta se valida exitosamente pero no se borra el registro

Tags: php, mysqli

¿Por que a pesar de que el `if` valida a `$data` cuando reviso en mi base de datos no se ha borrado ningún registro?

```
<?php
    require("conexion.php");
    error_reporting(0);
    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $borrar = "DELETE FROM nuevosingresos WHERE ID = '$id'";
    
    $data = mysqli_query($conexion, $borrar);
    
    if($data){
        echo "Registro eliminado correctamente";
        //header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error al intentar eliminar registro";
    }
?>
```

Comment: No deberías desactivar las notificaciones de error, eso te impide ver si algo no esta funcionando en tu query

Comment: Muestra el id que estas pasando a la consulta... capaz no hay nada con ese id?

Comment: Acabo de hacer el ```echo``` del ```$borrar``` y resulta que no esta obteniendo ningun valor la variable, esto es lo que sale despues de hacer el ```echo``` ```DELETE FROM nuevosingresos WHERE id = '$fila[id]'``` en el html tengo una linea de codigo que es la que creo que esta fallando es esta ```DELETE FROM nuevosingresos WHERE id = '$fila[id]'```

Comment: @GerardoTopete agrega tu código html

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `delete` en `mysqli_query` retorna `false` si hay un error. Pero si no tiene error tu query puede ser que el registro no existe o no coincida con tu filtro y aun así dará `true`.

Para hacer una verificación de los registros eliminados sería con `mysqli_affected_rows`

```
<?php
    require("conexion.php");
    error_reporting(0);
    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $borrar = "DELETE FROM nuevosingresos WHERE ID = '$id'";
    
    $data = mysqli_query($conexion, $borrar);
    
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexion) > 0){
        echo "Registro eliminado correctamente";
        //header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error al intentar eliminar registro";
    }
?>
```

> mysqli_affected_rows — Obtiene el número de filas afectadas en la
> última operación MySQL (INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE).

También te recomiendo imprimir tu query

```
echo $borrar;
```

Y el resultado ejecútalo en phpMyAdmin u otro manejador de MySQL para ver que mensaje te envía.